# Mobile Safari won't stop caching

Tags: html, mobile-safari, offline-caching

I'm writing an offline app for mobile Safari.

I have just gotten to the point where it will create the app icon on the home screen and function offline.

Now I want to update the HTML in my app, but it refuses to refresh.
I've trIed the refresh button, the "clear cache" settings option, I have even taken down the server but safari still shows the page.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the cache manifest. You can just add a comment line to the manifest. When you do, the browser will redownload the whole app.

More info about this topic can be found here: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html#debugging
Your situation kind of applies to the title :)